# Is it correct to say "somebody is integrate'?

Tags: adjectives

In a conversation, it happened to me to say "James is integrate.". I meant he is a man of integrity.".

My question is how strange my sentence sounds to a native speaker? and was it still understandable? Does it make sense to say "James is integrated"?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of your sentences would be understood by a native speaker to mean that James is a man of integrity. You need to say that he is a "man of integrity" or that he "has integrity." There's no adjective form of the word "integrity" that I've ever heard.

In fact, if you say that "James is integrated" you would be seriously misunderstood to mean that James has integrated - meaning (possibly) that he has adapted to his environment.